# Nginx SSL setup adding unexpected port to nodejs URI redirect

Tags: ssl, nginx-config

I'm trying to set up Nginx web server for authentication service, all things are good in localhost but when I add ssl to my server, the redirect from nodejs server (another server) automatically add port in the URI (like 9001 in the image)

This is my file in nginx

```
server {
    server_name server.com www.server.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    //certificate here
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


}
server {
    if ($host = www.account.vicodemy.tech) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = account.vicodemy.tech) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen 80;
    server_name server.com www.server.com;
    return 404;
```

This is the unexpected port that is attached to my domain

[The Strange 9001 port URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znX0C.png)